# "System.Drawing.Image" cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a registration form with a picture in `VB.Net` using an Access database.  Utilizing the following code, I am getting an error.

```
Me.Student_instructorTableAdapter.Insert(txtname,txtpass, ***PictureBox1.Image***)
Me.Student_instructorTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DatabaseDataSet4.student_instructor)

MsgBox("Successfully added", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
```

The `PictureBox1.Image` is saving into an Access Database ("picture") which throws an error:

> "System.Drawing.Image" cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array"

What should I use instead of `PictureBox1.Image` when I call `Insert` in order to avoid the exception?

Answer (score 2):

(Should be a comment but I need to post code)

We need the full exception message to know exactly what it's expecting (1-dimensional array of *what*?) Most likely it's a Byte array.

If so, you can convert an image to a Byte array like this...

```
Public Function ImageToByteArray(imageIn As System.Drawing.Image) As Byte()
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    Return ms.ToArray()
End Function
```

You can convert a Byte array back to an image like this...

```
Public Function byteArrayToImage(byteArrayIn As Byte()) As Image
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(byteArrayIn)
    Dim returnImage As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    Return returnImage
End Function
```

[See here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv) for more information

I'm not familiar with access data types so it may support images directly. If so, you need to make sure that you've got the right data type selected for that column/field.

Incidentally, if you don't have to, don't use Access (or at least the storage engine/JET) for new projects - it's slow, unreliable with more than 10 users and has serious security issues. If you don't want a full-up SQL Server database, consider SQL Compact Edition (CE) or SQL Express.

Comment: No you pretty much called needs the stream of the image which can be converted to byte[] and go in a column of type image.